# why am I unable to view Certificate Information

Tags: openssl, certificates

I run these command to generate private and public keys :

```
openssl genrsa -out keypair.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in keypair.pem -pubout -out publickey.crt
```

and then I tried to view certicate information using

```
openssl x509 -text -in publickey.crt  -noout
```

but I am getting this error:

```
unable to load certificate
140464089126208:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

any idea of why and how can I manage to view the certificate ?

Thanks

Comment: You have generated private and public keys but not any certificate.

Comment: @admstg Why don't you make that an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You have generated private and public keys but not any certificate.

You need to create a certificate request with `openssl req -key keypair.pem -new -out domain.csr` then else autosign the certificate with `openssl x509 -signkey dkeypair.pem -in domain.csr -req -days 365 -out domain.crt` or request your PKI to sign the .csr